# Auto layout backwards compatibility in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, backwards-compatibility

I couldn't find in Apple's documentation ([Cocoa Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH1-SW1)) what is the lowest iOS version that supports this feature, nor any posts related to iOS... maybe it only depends on Xcode version, and not on iOS version? I need to develop an iOS app that should be compatible from the latest iOS version down to 4.3

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autolayout was introduced at WWDC 2012 and is supported starting on iOS 6. It'll definitely not work with iOS 4.3.

I strongly recommend you to think about if you really need to support iOS 4.3 these days. We're *probably* very close to have iOS 7 now and you'll be years behind (technologically speaking) supporting iOS 4.3. I understand apps that are currently supporting iOS 4.3, but I don't think it's a good idea do *start* developing an app now with iOS 4.3 support in mind.

Comment: Yes, I know that supporting from iOS 4.3 will have a lot of technical drawbacks, and additional complexity at development, but I was given that requirement. Thanks for answering

Comment: Have another question... is it possible to check in code the current running iOS version, and take advantage of auto layout if version is 6+? Or simply I can't use the feature at all?

Comment: Never tried, but I don't think it's a good idea at all. You would probably need to do the work twice.

Answer (score 2):

One way to find this out quickly is to set the deployment target of the XIB/Storyboard file directly. By default, it's set to the latest SDK version. Open the XIB/SB, and in the File Inspector (right panel), choose 4.3 (or whatever you like) as your deployment target.

[image: Example of an illegal configuration]

If Auto Layout is enabled, Xcode will show an "Illegal Configuration" error for that file:

[image: Illegal Configuration Error]

As you can see, it's iOS 6+ only. Auto Layout uses new APIs at runtime, so using the latest Xcode version does not help, and you cannot use Auto Layout conditionally in a XIB. You could, however, have separate XIBs for different system versions, but it sounds like a lot of (maintenance) work.

Setting the correct deployment target has another benefit: You will be warned if you use classes that have been introduced later than your deployment target.

[image: Unavailable Class Error]